# How to set agent metrics for managed group

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver

I would like to set auto-scaling for my GCE instances. I read the documentations and I understood that I can set a custom metric as the factor to allow google autoscaler to resize my cluster. Now, I would like to set the **memory/percent_used** as the metric and I did it but what I see is a wrong value because I receive always *100* as the value. Seeing in stackdriver I can see the metric and I also can see the right value. But In StackDriver I see the metric settled like this `memory/percent_used:gce_instance(used, 124567892364, europe-west1-d, project-123456)`. I tried to set the same in the GCE auto-scale options but I receive an error *metric does not exist*. Is there someone that can help me and tell me how I can set the right metric or give me some links for reading about this?

Answer (score 0):

For now, seems to be impossible to use the metric for achieving that goal. 
I have opened a thread in google groups at this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/gce-discussion/X6LA0-8mFak/RVwOn2rjCgAJ) where you can follow the evolving of the discussion.

**TL;DR**

The windows agent sends metrics using some labels and the *google cloud autoscale for managed group* can't filter that labels at the moment. So, the *100%* value that you see is the sum of *free memory* and *used memory*. They are working to implement the labels filtering into the option of the managed group, Google team wrote.

**UPDATE**

I wrote a small client for achieving this goal. I used JS (node.js) for doing that. You could find the application at this [github link](https://github.com/beinnova/stackdriver-monitor/blob/master/monitor.js). Hope this can help someone.